# PostgreSQL pg_xlog folder's files

Tags: database, export, dump, postgresql-9.2

I have a `PostgreSQL` "data" directory from my previous database.
when I cut this directory in the "data" directory from default installation of PostgreSQL and try to run my PostgreSQL it return this error:

> could not open file "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000012" (log file 0,
>   segment 18): No such file or directory could not open file
>   "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000011" (log file 0, segment 17): No such
>   file or directory

How can i find these log files?
How PostgreSQL create these files?

Comment: I try to create file with those names but returned this error:

"could not read from log file 0, segment 18, offset 0: No such file or directory"

"could not read from log file 0, segment 17, offset 0: No such file or directory"

Comment: what you mean "when I cut this directory"?.. do you try to copy cluster this way?..

Comment: I replaced it with "data " directory from default installation.

Comment: yes - but why? wht did you try to achieve?..

Answer (score 1):

In order to "copy" cluster, you should follow instructions from link:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-file.html

> There are two restrictions
>
> 1. The database server must be shut down in order to get a usable backup.
> 2. If you have dug into the details of the file system layout of the database, you might be tempted to try to back up or restore only
>      certain individual tables or databases from their respective files or
>      directories. This will **not** work

After you just overwrote the "cut" directory you made the cluster unusable - build a new one